# Is there any alternative ways to implement the Security actions which are obsolete

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, code-access-security

I Have a C++ application built with .net framework 4.6.2 and now i am trying to upgrade the library to .NET6.0.

I have security actions attributes specified in multiple places as below.

```
[assembly:SecurityPermission(SecurityAction::RequestMinimum, UnmanagedCode = true)];


[System::Security::Permissions::SecurityPermissionAttribute(System::Security::Permissions::SecurityAction::Demand, SerializationFormatter=true)]
```

As the code access security CAS is obsolete , while trying to build the c++ library with .net6.0 in VS 2022 i am getting the error saying "error C4950: 'System::Security::Permissions::SecurityAction': marked as obsolete".

So, am trying to find alternative ways if any to implement the security actions.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't "implement" them - just **remove them**. If you need to multi-target .NET 4.6.2 _and_ .NET 6.0 then use `#ifdef` to exclude those lines from the compiled source (but alas, I cannot think of any legitimate reason to multi-target an obsolete and out-of-support .NET Framework version _and_ .NET 6.0 at the same time).

Comment: @Dai , Thanks for the response, we are not going to keep the 4.6.2 version anymore , we are just upgrading it to .net 6 and going to use it,   As you suggested if we remove the security action implementation from code then wont there be any impact due to removing it?

Comment: Correct, there will be no negative consequences of removing the obsolete and unused Code Access Security attributes from your code. That's why MS flagged them with `[Obsolete]`.